# how to access phpmyadmin with password

Tags: phpmyadmin, wampserver

how do I access phpmyadmin/Wampserver(interface) if I have assigned it a password, is there any page where you can input the password?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the automatic access in your configuration  just change **$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']** to **true** argument if it's not.

Example:

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

It will allow you to automatically access to your phpmyadmin base on your pass and login.

If you would like to input your own login and password in **phpmyadmin** page just change the true argument back to false in the config file.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but in case anyone needs to know

Go to your xampp folder, open phpmyadmin folder
Open the config.inc php file on text editor

You should see
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

Just input your password in there, save it and try connecting again
example: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '**1234**';

Answer (score -1):

When you access your host via an address which ends with `phpmyadmin`, you will be prompted for the username and password you assigned. If you didn't specify a username, try 'root'

Try:

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
```

This was from [How to setup Your Own Wampserver](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-set-up-your-own-wampserver/)

Comment: my problem is how can I access it directly from the web browser if I have already put a password in it.
Of course I can always change the password into no using mysql but the question is accessing it on the web browser.

Comment: So why wouldn't the URL work? Presumably you put in at least a root password (for *mysql* , so give 'root' as the username, and whatever password you specified for root. Is `localhost` the problem?

Answer (score -2):

Try **root** as username and let the password **empty** ( don't type anything ) 
It worked for me.